# Database Modeling of a Softball League

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am modeling a database for use in a softball league website. I'm not that experienced in DB Modeling, and I'm having a hard time with a question about the future.

Right now I have the following tables:

players table (player_id, name, gender, email, team_id)

teams table (team_id, name, captain[player_id], logo, wins_Regular_season, losses_regular_season)

regular_season table (game_id, week, date, home[team_id], away[team_id], home_score, away_score, rain_date)

playoff table (pgame_id, date, home[team_id], away[team_id], home_score, away_score, winnerTo[pgame_id], loserTo[pgame_id])

To make the data persist from season to season, but to also have an easy way to access the data should I:

A) include a year column in the tables and then filter my queries by year?
B) create new tables every year?
C) Do something else that makes more sense but that I can't think of.

Comment: You don't need the wins/losses in the team table - you have a possiblity for integrity issues there, and you already record wins/losses in the `regular_season` table and `playoff` table.

Comment: So when showing a standings page I would query the regular_season table for the games that a team played and what the scores were and then figure out the win/loss records from that? Seems like a lot of work for every time I load that page.

Comment: @Jeremy - If all you need is the count of wins/losses, it would simply be a longish WHERE clause along the lines of `WHERE (home = XX AND Home_Score > away_Score) OR (away = xx AND away_score > home_score)`

Comment: @JNK - I didn't even think of that. Thanks man that's really slick.

Comment: @Jeremy - the danger with having that data in two places is that you don't get it updated in one of them.  When you have 5 wins 3 losses recorded in the `teams` table but the `regular_season` table shows 4 wins 4 losses, did you mis-record one in the `regular_season` table or did something get miskeyed in the `teams` table or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This design is not only bad about the future. It is also wrong regarding the *past*. You're not keeping history in a proper way.

Let's suppose a player changes team: how would that fit into this design? It should be easy to get that kind of information...

And the best way of doing that (IMHO) would be also representing the *season* as an entity, as a concrete table. Then you should replicate this information in each relationship. Meaning, for instance, that a player does not simply belong to a team: he belongs to a team *in a specific season*, and may belong to another team when the season changes.

OTOH, I don't think it's wise to keep `regular_season` and `playoff` as distinct tables: they could be easily merged into one, by adding some sort of flag in order to keep that information.

**Edit** This is what I'm meaning:

[image]

- Notice that there is a `Season` table.
- A `Player` belongs to a `Team` **in** a `Season`.
- **NO NEED TO DUPLICATE ANYTHING**. A team has only **ONE** record in the DB; a player will be associated to only **ONE** record.
- I did **NOT** design the `Playoff` table, because I believe it should not exist. If the OP disagrees, just add it.

That way you can keep track of all seasons, without needing to replicate the whole DB. I think this is also better than using a `year` column, which is not meaningful, and cannot be easily constrained (like a foreign key can).

But, please, feel free to disagree.

Comment: Players can't change teams during the season in this league. So I think that having a year column in the player table will relate them season by season to their team using the Team_id.

Comment: @Jeremy: I don't think you understood me. My answer is also based upon the fact that player's **can't** change teams during season (it would be much more complex if they could).

Comment: @Jeremy - What he's saying is, you add a year to the `Team` table and each team gets a new id each year.  Then you easily know who played for the `2010 Bears` and the `2011 Bears` since they are unique entities/records.

Comment: @rsenna @JNK - That makes sense and I was planning on doing that after we had the conversation about adding year to the different tables.

Comment: @JNK: no, I'm **NOT** saying that... I'll post a diagram, so people can understand (and *perhaps* stop downvoting me).

Comment: @rsenna - That makes more sense. Thanks for the picture.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way would be to add year columns to your tables. That way you can easily call up the past with a select query, or view. SQL Server has good support for this.  I've dealt with cleanup of the other route, and it isn't pretty after a few years of data have accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option A and have a year column in the seasons table and playoff table.

Comment: He'd need it in the players and team tables too, since players can change teams and teams can change captains.

Comment: Ahh so each year you would have another entry for every player? That would work out very well for maintaining the players stats each season.

Comment: So since we have 2 seasons I could do a column in each table sort of like "2011S" for summer 2011 and "2011F" for fall 2011...but what I worry about is that after 5 or 6 seasons the database will start getting over run with tons of data.

Say there are 16 teams with 16 players each that play 15 games each and a playoffs every year that seeds each of the 16 teams in a double elimination style.

That's 16 team entries, 16 player entries, and over 100 games per season.

Will I run into a space issue on the DB down the line?

Comment: You might be surprised at how many records need to be in a table before you see a real performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a date column, you can use that to find the year

```
SELECT * FROM regular_season WHERE YEAR(date) = 2011
```

Comment: This wouldn't resolve the issue with players changing teams or captains changing on a team from year to year.